# plotting data separated by semicolon

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I think this question is rather simple however i couldn´t figure it out yet... i want to import a file where data columns are separated by semicolons instead of blank spaces. For the `somedata.dat` file everything is as expected, however when i create the same file with semicolons following error occurs

> ! File ended while scanning use of
>   \pgfplots@addplotimpl@table@fromfile.

The manual on page 52 states the expression `[col sep=semicolon]` for changing the column separation. I also tried to use `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` and add `\pgfplotstabletypeset{col sep = semicolon}` in the preamble however without success. I hope someone can clarify what i missed. Thanks for any help

```
\begin{filecontents*}{plots/data/somedata.dat}
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{plots/data/somedata_sc.dat}
 1;2
 3;4
 5;6
 7;8
 9;10
 \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={plots/data},} %data is located at a sub folder

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table {somedata.dat};%no problem for this one
        \addplot table [col sep=semicolon] {somedata_sc.dat}%error on this
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Typo on your end, you're missing the semicolon at the end of the `\addplot` line (and `\end{document}`).

Comment: the \end document was actually included just badly copied, however you were absolutely right about the semicolon. Thanks alot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.